# Qual o uso da sigla M.A.R.I.O para o aprendizado da linguage portuguesa?

Tags: verbos

Me deparei com a sigla MARIO que significa:

> **M**ediar, **A**nsiar, **R**emediar, **I**ncendiar e **O**diar

Qual o objetivo disso para o estudo da língua?

Comment: Primeira vez que ouço falar dela mas o primeiro _hit_ da minha busca no Google [revelou](https://www.vestibular.com.br/dica/verbos-terminados-em-iar-e-a-maravilhosa-regra-do-mario/) que se trata de "verbos com a mesma terminação também fogem à regra dos regulares terminados em -iar. São cinco os mais importantes: mediar, ansiar, remediar, incendiar e odiar.". Parece claro. Ou não entendi qual sua dúvida? (Ou não há dúvida e você só quer introduzir esse conteúdo no Portuguese SE?)

Comment: @stafusa agregar conteúdo ao site. Eu entendo os sites da SE como repositórios de conhecimento e não como sites de ajudas rápidas para resolver problemas próprios, o propósito é agregar conteúdo, servindo como uma boa fonte. **Eu mesmo iria responder a pergunta aqui (https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)**, mas sempre que formulo uma pergunta eu procuro dar a oportunidade de outros responderem.

Comment: Ótimo, Guilherme. Também já fiz algumas perguntas com o mesmo objetivo.

Comment: Lembrete: Guilherme, ainda está dando oportunidade de outros responderem ou se esqueceu da pergunta? :)

Comment: @stafusa meu foco no site é sempre dar a oportunidade das pessoas participarem e tentar atrair participantes novos, através de temas atuais ligados ao escopo, já deixei de responder muita pergunta própria visando tentar melhorar o site (aqui e o SOpt) :) ... infelizmente sinto que mesmo o site sendo ótimo, é complicado atrair pessoas para cá.